# Visual-C++ inline assembler NEAR JMP

Tags: visual-c++, assembly, masm

How can I use a relative near jmp in MSVC inline assembler?

I tried the following:

```
__asm { 
    jmp 0x00000011
}
```

But it raises an error error:

> ... error C2415: invalid operand

So, how can a relative near jump be realised? I need the jmp instruction with opcode E9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
__asm
{
    jmp $+0x11
}
```